# How do I use the Black code formatter for python code. Where do I run its commands?

Tags: python, spyder, black-code-formatter

I want to format my code according to a set of rules. So I want to use te [Black](https://github.com/psf/black) code formatter.
I have installed it using
`pip install black`
Its documentation does not have detailed guidelines on how to use it. Can you please help? I want to use it in spyder anaconda preferably.

Edit: I just read that spyder does not support Black editor as of now.
So please can you tell me how do I use it?

Comment: The [readme](https://github.com/psf/black#usage) does, in fact, contain a **Usage** section. How did this not work?

Comment: Where do I run those commands?? When I run in python terminal it shows invalid syntax error